# How to integrate by Scipy in self-defined functions without warning?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I want to integrate my self-defined functions by Scipy. But it shows integration warning. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, exp
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as sp


def fw(x):
    f0 = 1
    thetaM = 70*(np.pi/180)
    return exp(-f0**(-2)*np.sin(x)**2/np.sin(thetaM)**2)


def I00(q,z):
    k = 2*pi/(800 *10**(-9))
    intg = lambda x: fw(x)*sqrt(cos(x))*sin(x)*(1+cos(x))*sp.jv(0,k*q*sin(x))*exp(1j*k*z*cos(x))
    y, err = integrate.quad(intg, 0, 100)
    return y
```

And it shows:

```
nan
C:\Users\Timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:448: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
D:/Tim/PythonScripts/ffcalc/integrals.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  intg = lambda x: fw(x)*sqrt(cos(x))*sin(x)*(1+cos(x))*sp.jv(0,k*q*sin(x))*cos(k*z*cos(x))
C:\Users\Timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
```

How could I fix this issue? (IntegrationWarning)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Show the actual call of `I00(q, z)` that triggered the error.  What values of `q` and `z` did you use?

Comment: You have the expression `exp(1j*k*z*cos(x))` in the integrand.  `scipy.integrate.quad` can only integrate real-valued functions.  You should verify that your integrand correctly computes real values over the interval of integration.

Comment: q and z are both real values

Comment: Tim, add that error message to the question, where it will be easier to read.  You have `sqrt(cos(x))` in your function.  That will raise an error if the value of `x` is such that `cos(x)` is negative.  Stop trying to call `quad`, and instead focus on ensuring that the integrand is being calculated correctly.

Comment: *"q and z are both real values"*  Please give the actual values, so someone can try to reproduce exactly the same problem that you are seeing.

Comment: After I chagne the exp(1j*k*zcos(x)) to real value (cos(k*z*cos(x))), it shows: `nan D:/Tim/PythonScripts/ffcalc/integrals.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt intg = lambda x: fw(x)*sqrt(cos(x))*sin(x)*(1+cos(x))*sp.jv(0,kqsin(x))*exp(1*kz*cos(x)) C:\Users\Timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved. The error may be underestimated. warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning) `

Comment: `q` is from `0` to `10**(-6)` and  `z` is from `-10**(-6)` to `10**(-6)`

Comment: Thanks! Warren. I figure out why.